# PythonのAnacondaの導入方法？

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

Anaconda を導入して、下記のコードを入力するとエラーになりました。
Anaconda のファイルが足りないみたいですが、デフォルトインストールなので検討がつきません。解決方法を教えて頂けないでしょうか。

## コード

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
```

## エラー内容

```
>>> import openpyxl
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 312, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 268, in read
    self.read_manifest()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 136, in read_manifest
    src = self.archive.read(ARC_CONTENT_TYPES)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\zipfile.py", line 1428, in read
    with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\zipfile.py", line 1467, in open
    zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3_2\lib\zipfile.py", line 1395, in getinfo
    'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
```

## Anaconda の導入、環境

Anaconda からダウンロード
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/
Anaconda 2019.03 for Windows Installer
Python 3.7 versionの「64-Bit Graphical Installer (662 MB)」をダウンロード

## 環境

Windows 10

Comment: 本件においてAnacondaは関係なく、「 `openpyxl` というライブラリで `KeyError: "There is no item named '[Content_Types].xml' in the archive"
` というエラーが出た」、というのがタイトルにふさわしいように感じます。

Comment: `conda list` の結果を質問文に追記していただけますか？（[編集]から追記が可能です）

Answer (score 1):

皆様、ありがとうございます。
自己解決できました。
原因は、OpenOfficeを使っていたことでした。異なるフリーソフトを導入したらうまくいきました。